# How can i add statistical values in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, model, statistics, gridextra

For my masterthesis i need to create 5 multiplots , each containing 12 Scatterplots. And i need to add the statistical values RMSE, MAE and MBE.
these eq. are:

```
rmse(sim, obs, na.rm = TRUE)
mae(sim, obs, na.rm = TRUE)
mean((sim - obs), na.rm = TRUE)
```

I need to add this values automatically in the plots. My code is:

```
ggplot(data=Bad_Lauchstaedt, mapping=aes(x= `one_h_gap_L`, y= `BL 2-1`))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE, color="red")+
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, color="darkgray", size=1.2)+
  geom_point(color="darkblue", shape=1)+
  labs(y="measured data", x="gap filled data by lysimeters", title = "best fit lysimeters")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())+
  xlim(0,0.8)+
  ylim(0,0.8)+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0),"pt"))+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = R_sqr,
               rr.digits = 3,parse = TRUE,
               size=7)
```

Comment: The ggpmisc package might have what you're looking for.https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpmisc/versions/0.3.6

Comment: i already use this package for R², as shown in the code. But how can i use it for the other statistical values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my code i found this answer:

```
label <- df%>% 
  summarize(RMSE = rmse(sim, obs, na.rm = TRUE),
            MAE = mae(sim, obs, na.rm = TRUE),
            MBE = mean( (sim - obs), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(
    posx = 0.5, posy = 0.05,
    label = glue("RMSE = {round(RMSE, 3)} <br> MAE = {round(MAE, 3)} <br> MBE = {round(MBE, 3)} ")) 

p +
  geom_richtext(
    data = label,
    aes(posx, posy, label = label),
    hjust = 0, vjust = 0,
    size = 4,
    fill = "white", label.color = "black")
```